# PHP SQL Server, call a stored procedures with parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i'm facing this next problem:

i made a stored procedure as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE verify_user_connection
@username nvarchar(50),
@pass nvarchar(50)
AS

BEGIN

SELECT users.username, users.pass 
FROM dbo.users
WHERE users.username = '@username'
AND users.pass = '@pass'

RETURN '@username'

END
```

and from the PHP code i call him like this:

```
  <?php
  /* Handle form buttons. */
  if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) || !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['pass'];
      $sql = "{ CALL dbo.verify_user_connection (@username = ?, @pass = ?) }";
      $param = array($username, $password);
      $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $param);
      $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result);
      echo $row;
      if (!$row) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
      }
      else {
        echo "record found";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "something went wrong";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

well i'm kinda new in SQLSRV driver of microsoft and i know my syntax is not accurate here
could someone inlight my problem and explain to me what am i doing wrong??

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know php at all, but on your sp you should remove the `'` of your variables: `users.username = @username AND users.pass = @pass RETURN @username`

Answer (score 1):

This is'nt going to be much help, but the most reliable mthod for using SQL Server and SP's that I've found is by using PHP ADODB ( http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#download ) to connect and call procs.

I have always found the in-built sql server functions patchy at best when working with SQL server.

If you are still struggling I am happy to give you more info via email.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'll try to avoid using external plugins for simple actions , i believe that microsoft has thought about SP when they made their driver,

Comment: It's not the driver it's the php functions. OK... I have been working with SQL Server and PHP for many years and this is the only reliable solution.